# Executions/min and CPI ms/sec inside Activity Monitor is too high

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, activity-monitor

We have executions/min is too high, around 20,000 to 30,000 for a query. Does this means the query is executing 20,000 per minute? I don't think we have that much load on server that a single query runs 20,000 per minute.

Also, I am always confused with CPU ms/sec. Does this means total CPU used per second? If yes how come we have lot of queries with 1000+ CPU ms/sec as we have limited CPU on server.

Comment: What is the source of the message, monitoring tool ?

Comment: Activity Monitor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way to run a query very many times is to use a scalar user defined function as that will execute once per row in the query.

If you have multiple CPU cores each one can support 1000ms / second which is why total CPU appear strange and go over what seems possible

Comment: executions/min means query is executing 20,000 times per minutes?

Comment: Yes which is 333 execs / sec - that seems entirely possible.

To get to the bottom of why your server has a high number of executions you are going to need to run Query Store, Extended Events or a Trace. Probably the quickest and easiest way for you is to use Erik's SP which will create an extended events session and analyze the results for you

https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sp_humanevents/

They've been 3 recs on my answer - so I'd like to know in what way it is deficient so I can add additional details and you then feel able to accept it - thanks